# can't use replace function when upload files API on asp.net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I work on ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API and face an issue: I can't use replace function to change the name property of a selected file that I get when uploaded.

When I try like this:

```
string fileName = DisplayFileName.Replace(".xlsx", "-") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xlsx";
```

I get an error

> Iform file doesn't contain definition for replace and no accessible extension method Replace accepting first argument of iformfile

Full sample is here:

```
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public IActionResult Upload()
{
        try
        {
            var DisplayFileName = Request.Form.Files[0];
            string fileName = DisplayFileName.Replace(".xlsx", "-") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xlsx";
            string Month = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
            string DirectoryCreate = myValue1 + Month;

            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);

            if (!Directory.Exists(DirectoryCreate))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(DirectoryCreate);
            }

            if (DisplayFileName.Length > 0)
            {
                var filedata = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(Request.Form.Files[0].ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                var dbPath = Path.Combine(DirectoryCreate, fileName);
              
                using (var stream = new FileStream(dbPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    Request.Form.Files[0].CopyTo(stream);
                }

                return Ok(new { dbPath });
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
        }
}
```

How to solve this issue?
sample

suppose i select file developed.xlsx

then after use replace or any way result will be

developed-sddfn78888.xlsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.IO.Path` to get filename and get file extension from request files.
Change this
`string fileName = DisplayFileName.Replace(".xlsx", "-") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xlsx";`
To

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(DisplayFileName.FileName);
string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(DisplayFileName.FileName);
string newFileName = $"{filename}-{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}{fileExtension}";
```

Otherwise, you could modify your code to

```
 string fileName = DisplayFileName.FileName.Replace(".xlsx", "-") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xlsx";
```